# What is the probability of pulling 2 specific cards in a hand of 8 from 78 cards?

Tags: probability, card-games

I drew a hand that contains the Sun and the Moon from a tarot deck with $78$ cards.
I want to find the probability of this occurring.
I think because there are $78 \choose 6$ distinct arrangements of the $6$ other cards in the hand, and $78\choose8$ distinct hands, the probability of choosing both the Sun and the Moon is $$\frac{78 \choose 6}{78 \choose 8}=1/9.$$
But $1/9$ seems pretty high. Am I missing something?

Comment: The numerator is wrong.  You are choosing the other $6$ cards from a deck of $76$ (since the two chosen cards are not available).

Comment: The [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) should be of help here.

Comment: Are there other 'special' pairs of cards that might also have caught your attention? (In order to be called a 'miracle', occurrence of a very rare event has to be predicted in advance.)

Comment: I don't think $\frac {78 \choose 6}{78\choose 8} = \frac 19$ but actually closer to $\frac 1{99}$.  The actual probability (as per lulu's comment and stackers answer) is $\frac {76\choose 6}{78\choose 8}$ so the probability is actually $\frac {71\cdot 70}{78\cdot 77}\approx 0.82$ smaller.

Answer (score 1):

It would be

$$\frac{1\cdot{76\choose 6}}{{78\choose 8}}\approx0.009324009$$

where you can replace $1$ with ${2\choose 2}$

Answer (score 1):

Simulation (to check):

```
deck = c(1,1,rep(0,76))
table(deck)
deck
 0  1 
76  2 

set.seed(406)
sm = replicate(10^6, sum(sample(deck,8)))
mean(sm==2)
[1] 0.009219       # aprx 0.0093
sd(sm==2)/1000
[1] 9.557206e-05   # 95% marg of sim err
```

Simulated value is $0.0092 \pm 0.0001.$

```
choose(76, 6)/choose(78,8)
[1] 0.009324009
```